# Lose WiFi connection after suspend Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, laptop

Whenever the computer goes to sleep or is otherwise suspended, the WiFi connection is lost, no networks are found.

Running Ubuntu 20.04 on a new Huawei Matebook D 15, problem has been happening since Ubuntu installed.

When I run `sudo wlp1s0 up`, as other questions recommend, it says something along the lines of `Operation already in progress`, and no combination of `wlp1s0 down` etc changes it.

The clearest output describing the problem is that running `lspci -v` after suspend includes

```
01:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter (rev ff) (prog-if ff)
    !!! Unknown header type 7f
    Kernel driver in use: rtw_8822ce
    Kernel modules: rtw88_8822ce
```

and

```
00:01.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge (rev ff) (prog-if ff)
    !!! Unknown header type 7f
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
```

Does anyone know what might be happening?

Comment: print out `iwconfig` and `ip link show`

Answer (score 0):

I really like the question. Even, I faced the same issue in Kali not in Ubuntu. And, it would be better if you post this question in [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com). Askubuntu is only for ubuntu. If it is ubuntu configuration issue than, peoples from askubuntu may answer the question better way. I am adding some links of question related to yours.

1. [wlan0 isn't working most of times](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/641080/wlan0-isnt-working-most-of-times)
2. [Wifi isnt working after using wifite [duplicate]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/640890/wifi-isnt-working-after-using-wifite)  (I highly recommend to read comment in this question).
3. [Unable to connect to wlan0 (Kali)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/643319/unable-to-connect-to-wlan0-kali)
4. [unable to connect to wireless connection](https://superuser.com/questions/1639365/unable-to-connect-to-wireless-connection)

I am adding some information of that which is more likely to be your answer.

---

create a file named `wifi-workaround.sh` in `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/`. To making the file executable `chmod a+rx /lib/systemd/system-sleep/wifi-workaround.sh`. Add following scripts to `wifi-workaround.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
# When suspending/resuming, systemd will call executables in /lib/systemd/system-sleep 
# with the following parameters:
# $1 = either "pre" or "post"
# $2 = "suspend", "hibernate", "hybrid-sleep" or "suspend-then-hibernate"
INTERFACE=wlan0
DRIVER_MODULE=<driver module name>    

case "$1" in
    pre)
        nmcli device disconnect $INTERFACE
        modprobe -r $DRIVER_MODULE
        ;;
    post)
        modprobe $DRIVER_MODULE
        nmcli device connect $INTERFACE
        ;;
esac

# Don't stop suspending/resuming even if we fail somehow.
exit 0
```

[Answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/641194/449077).

---

When I did the thing I notice my wireless was working fine and when I suspend and turn my laptop on wlan0 was working fine but, `Mobile Broadband` wasn't working. I didn't need `Mobile Broadband` that's why I didn't do any changes. But, after making the changes nearly 6-7 days later I was suspending lot of times(I suspended nearly 10 times in 3-4 minutes) when I wlan0 was permanently gone. That's why nowadays I stop suspending anymore.. I just shutdown. And, I think it may not be your answer.. But, I highly recommend to do thing after you understand anything... In some answers of above question is very risky... You can try what I said....

Thanks

Comment: I found another question which is for lan not wlan0 that's why I am not editing my question [Ubuntu 18.04 - Ethernet disconnected after suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029250/ubuntu-18-04-ethernet-disconnected-after-suspend#1058760). You can visit the question also..