# Unable to connect to wlan0 (Kali)

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, wlan, backports

I am running Kali Linux, and I was unable to connect to Wi-Fi. 
I was searching on the Internet for half an hour.  I tried a lot of things. 
Finally, I had installed Wi-Fi driver **compat-wireless**.

I know that it is deprecated. Although I tried cause, backport wasn't working properly. When I had unloaded **compat-wireless**. I got `wlan0` and `wlan1`. But, no wireless connection is showing.

[image: screenshot – wlan1 selected]

Last time when I tried that by restarting my laptop. I notice that those connection isn't visible anymore. Why it is happening? I earlier said that backport isn't working. When I unloaded backport. I get the error:

```
/--------------
| Your kernel headers are incomplete/not installed.
| Please install kernel headers, including a .config
| file or use the KLIB/KLIB_BUILD make variables to
| set the kernel to build against, e.g.
|   make KLIB=/lib/modules/3.1.7/
| to compile/install for the installed kernel 3.1.7
| (that isn't currently running.)
\--
make: *** [Makefile:41: unload] Error 1
```

I am adding screenshots of what I said/tried.

```
┌──(istiak㉿kali)-[~]
└─$ sudo airmon-ng                                                          1 ⨯
[sudo] password for istiak: 

PHY Interface   Driver      Chipset

phy0    wlan0       iwlwifi     Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] (rev 34)
```

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

```
┌──(istiak㉿kali)-[~]
└─$ sudo ifconfig wlan0 up           
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Input/output error
```

I added most of them as source code which is needed.

```
iwconfig

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

wwan0     no wireless extensions.

docker0   no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off

wlan1     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off

hwsim0    no wireless extensions.
```

When I don't use laptop for few hours, wlan0 works fine again. 
But, using laptop 1-2 hours suddenly I face the issue again.

Look it is working fine:
[image: screenshot]
after leaving turn off laptop for 10-20 minutes. 
After updating the question I have lost my connection again.

```
┌──(istiak㉿kali)-[~]
└─$ ifconfig
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:d7:97:c3:66  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.109  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::4f08:a5d3:bba9:30fb  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether f0:de:f1:da:7d:80  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 174405  bytes 220965740 (210.7 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 52107  bytes 7856121 (7.4 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 20  memory 0xf2500000-f2520000  
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 170  bytes 19457 (19.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 170  bytes 19457 (19.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Output of `lspci`:

```
┌──(istiak㉿kali)-[~]
└─$ lspci -knn |grep Net -A2                                        255 ⨯

00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville) [8086:1502] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo ThinkPad T520 [17aa:21ce]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
--
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] [8086:0085] (rev 34)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 (802.11a/b/g/n) [8086:1311]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

Output of `lspci`:

```
┌──(istiak㉿kali)-[~]
└─$ iw dev  
phy#0
    Interface wlan0
        ifindex 3
        wdev 0x1
        addr a2:1e:b7:a8:76:10
        type managed
        txpower 15.00 dBm
```

I took two screenshot what was happening when I had wireless connection.

```
┌──(istiak㉿kali)-[~]
└─$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Xisilon.Xyz"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.417 GHz  Access Point: 0C:80:63:D1:53:20   
          Bit Rate=162 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=63/70  Signal level=-47 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:22   Missed beacon:0

wwan0     no wireless extensions.

docker0   no wireless extensions.
```

When I don't have wlan0.

```
┌──(istiak㉿kali)-[~]
└─$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.
eth0      no wireless extensions.
wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
wwan0     no wireless extensions.
docker0   no wireless extensions.
```

Output of `lspci`:

```
┌──(istiak㉿kali)-[~]
└─$ lspci             
      
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family KT Controller (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville) (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev b4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev b4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation QM67 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port Mobile SATA AHCI Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] (rev 34)
0d:00.0 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd PCIe SDXC/MMC Host Controller (rev 07)
```

I have Windows alongside Kali Linux. When I work in Windows while I don't Kali Linux wlan0 works well in Windows.

[image]
[image]

```
┌──(istiak㉿kali)-[~]
└─$ lsusb                   
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 08e6:34ec Gemalto (was Gemplus) Compact Smart Card Reader Writer
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 1199:9013 Sierra Wireless, Inc. Sierra Wireless Gobi 3000 Modem device (MC8355)
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c058 Logitech, Inc. M115 Mouse
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04f2:b217 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Lenovo Integrated Camera (0.3MP)
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:217f Broadcom Corp. BCM2045B (BDC-2.1)
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 147e:2016 Upek Biometric Touchchip/Touchstrip Fingerprint Sensor
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

[@telcoM](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/258991/telcom) I did as you said. But, my wlan0 is set to `DOWN`. I am unable to change the state also by doing as you said. Earlier, I was unable to changed the state also. :(

```
┌──(istiak㉿kali)-[~]
└─$ ip link show   
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f0:de:f1:da:7d:80 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 56:00:07:23:21:08 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff permaddr 10:0b:a9:cb:ff:ec
4: wwan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 26:99:71:e7:f1:f9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 02:42:4b:fe:c9:60 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
                                                                                                                                                                         
┌──(istiak㉿kali)-[~]
└─$ ip link set dev wlan0 up
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
                                                                                                                                                                         
┌──(istiak㉿kali)-[~]
└─$ sudo ip link set dev wlan0 up                                                                                                                                    2 ⨯
[sudo] password for istiak: 
RTNETLINK answers: Input/output error
```

**Finally, I have understood why I am having the issue. But, I don't know how to fix. When laptop gets hotter and hotter I lost my wireless connection. Between 23 minutes I lost my wireless connection.**
[image]

It's been 3 hours laptop is keep running today it's hotter enough also. But, Wireless connection is work well. I didn't make any changes...

Note: I don't have much more skill with Linux. I am very beginner level Linux user.

Comment: I had visited lot of questions in Unix but, none of them were helpful. Above question is very critical lot of people left kali for this reason. I was one them also. But, when I had installed Kali again. In 1-2 months I have faced the issue again. So, i have an idea that is `to delete wireless connection completely and reinstall it again` ~ Is there any possible way to do it? I searched it on Internet also but, I didn't get any solution

Comment: Kali is not the right distribution for a beginner. It is not intended to be used as a regular OS. Do yourself a favor and chose something more beginner friendly!

Comment: @Panki I have experience of Fedora, Mint, Ubuntu. But, I spend time on them less than 4-5 months. That's why I said that `I don't have much more skill of Linux. I am very beginner level Linux User.`

Comment: @Panki So, would you suggest me to use another Linux distro. Which Linux Distro will you suggest me please?

Comment: Anything that is not Kali and suits your needs. Kali is designed for exactly one thing, and that thing only (pentesting). I prefer Debian, but you should choose what you are most comfortable with. :)

Comment: By posting a picture of text, you make it impossible for potential helpers on phones, or text terminals. to see your text. You make it impossible for any of us to make a local copy for investigation. Rather, [Edit] your Question, copy and paste the text into your Question, select it and use the `{}` formatting tool.

Comment: @Panki Actually, I chose Kali for ethical hacking... and, Linux is better for programming. That's why I thought Kali would be better for me.

Comment: @waltinator Oh! Sorry. I will those as text when I will lose my connection again. And, thanks for information that some people uses SE on phones.

Comment: Please add the output of `lspci -knn |grep Net -A2` . compat-wireless is deprecated.

Comment: @GAD3R I have edited my question

Comment: Why did you effectively [cross-post this on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/q/1639365/167207)?

Answer (score 2):

So, one of your WiFi adapters is Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 (802.11a/b/g/n), handled by driver `iwlwifi`. The support for that WiFi chip has been included in the standard kernel since kernel version 2.6.35, so there really should be no need to use `compat-wireless` unless you are using an absolutely ancient version of Kali.

[Visiting the driver information page on wireless.wiki.kernel.org](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi), I found a note about the monitor mode with Intel WiFi chips:

> About the monitor / sniffer mode
>
> Our devices support monitor mode. When you have VHT APs around, you should load the iwlwifi module with
>
> `amsdu_size=3`
>
> This will put lots of pressure on the memory subsystem, but it will allow you to hear 12K long packets. **You may see firmware crashes in case you didn't set that module parameter.**

And what is `VHT`? Turns out it was the development name for what is now called 802.11ac. In other words, this note says, "if these a/b/g/n WiFi chips are used in monitor mode when there are 802.11ac base stations in range, you should use the `amsdu_size=3` module option, or else the chip firmware may crash often."

This might just be what is happening to you: the `iwconfig` output of "when you don't have wlan0" indicates the `wlan0` interface is still being detected by the driver: it just doesn't seem to be working correctly. Perhaps it's because the WiFi chip firmware has crashed?

There is also a note about WiFi chip power management that used to cause issues until it was disabled in kernel version 3.17. By installing `compat-wireless-2010-06-26-p` you've effectively **downgraded** the WiFi drivers of a modern Kali distribution to more than 10 years old versions, and most likely restored this old problem.

So, you should create a text file in `/etc/modprobe.d/` directory, with a `.conf` suffix, e.g. `/etc/modprobe.d/wifi0.conf`, and write the following text into it:

```
options iwlwifi amsdu_size=3
```

Then run `update-initramfs -u` as root (just in case the WiFi driver is loaded very early in the boot process) and reboot.

---

Your other WiFi adapter is still almost a complete mystery, since you have not revealed any information that would allow us to identify it. It seems to not be a PCI(e) device, since it does not appear in `lspci` listing. But as you ran `make unload` for `compat-wireless-2010-06-26-p`, one of the messages was:

```
Unloading ath...
modprobe: FATAL: Module ath is in use.
```

That suggests it might be an Atheros WiFi adapter of some kind... unfortunately there are a lot of Atheros WiFi chips, and the modern kernels have several Atheros WiFi chip drivers (each for a particular line of WiFi chips Atheros has either produced or bought from other manufacturers) that might be applicable. To identify the adapter, a `lsusb` listing might be helpful.

---

Regarding the error message:

```
/--------------
| Your kernel headers are incomplete/not installed.
| Please install kernel headers, including a .config
| file or use the KLIB/KLIB_BUILD make variables to
| set the kernel to build against, e.g.
|   make KLIB=/lib/modules/3.1.7/
| to compile/install for the installed kernel 3.1.7
| (that isn't currently running.)
\--
make: *** [Makefile:41: unload] Error 1
```

This indicates the `compat-wireless` thinks you might have kernel version 3.1.7 installed (but even it acknowledges it's not the kernel version that's currently running). 3.1.7 is a very old kernel version: even Kali 1.0.6 (released in year 2014) used kernel version 3.12.x. So this is most likely the obsolete `compat-wireless` displaying a false error message.

Comment: Yes! You are right that something is crashing. Cause, when I reboot from Linux and started Windows I notice I am unable to access wlan0 right there also. I tried as you said I had created a `/etc/modprobe.d/wifi0.conf` file. Then, write that texts to that file. Then, I had run `update-initramfs -u` as root. When i reboot laptop again. I am facing the same issue. when I run ifconfig wlan0 isn't showing. when I run iwconfig somehow wlan0 is showing. I think something wrong is happening with hard drive or something else. I am not thinking that it is an outer issue. It is an inner issue

Comment: [In that wireless information page](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi). I saw some firmware. Should I install and try any of them? I have print out `lsusb`..

Comment: `ifconfig` with no options will only show activated interfaces, `ifconfig -a` or `ip link show` should show all interfaces. Normally, when you're using a WiFi interface to connect to a network, the interface will be controlled by NetworkManager and `wpa_supplicant`. To use monitor-mode tools like `airmon-ng`/`aircrack-ng`, you'll need to first run `airmon-ng check kill` which will kill those services to stop them interfering with monitor operations. Restarting those services after your hacking run is complete will be *your* job.

Comment: Regarding firmware, just make sure the `firmware-iwlwifi` package is installed, and the package management should ensure you'll have the suitable firmware versions for your Kali kernel.

Comment: Sorry! How can I check `firmware-iwlwifi` is installed or not? Please! check my edited question...

Comment: When I turned on my laptop wlan0 wasn't working. But, it was showing. when I didn't that file which you told me to create. I am seeing that wlan0 is working fine. I will write another comment if I get same issue again...! :) Until then, wlan0 is working....

Comment: Look at my last edit of my question. I have found why I am having the issue...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I need glasses but you left out one crucial bit of information: the hardware. Check your equipment and what kind of **chipset** (eg Realtek, Broadcom etc) it uses. Then determine based on that information if any drivers are required by your flavor of Linux.

But from your images I see that you use Airmon. Your wifi may not support monitoring mode, again this is something that is usually determined by looking up the chipset. And if Airmon is already running this may interfere with normal operation, to be clear I don't think you can't connect to another wifi network while Airmon is running on the same device. Thus scanning may return nothing but that could be normal.

So my recommendations are:

- start again with a clean install of Kali, possibly in a virtual machine so you can do a snapshot of the initial install, try different things and revert changes
- determine exactly what hardware you have, and the chipset then look up for drivers if required
- then make sure wlan0/1 are recognized by your system
- scan for networks and try to connect to another network to verify that your wifi is properly configured and working

Then check that monitor mode is supported.

Type: `iw dev`
You should get output like this:

```
phy#0
    Interface wlan0
    ...
```

Then you can probe the capabilities of your wifi device eg: `iw phy phy0 info`
You should get output like:

```
    Supported interface modes:
         * IBSS
         * managed
         * AP
         * AP/VLAN
         * WDS
         * monitor
         * mesh point
```

Make sure you see monitor.

Comment: I print out `lspci` `iw dev`. And, I am sure that when `mode/type` is set to monitor wlan0 doesn't work. [Visit the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/641194/449077) it was working few days properly. But, yesterday I was suspending my laptop lot of times. Than, I am getting the same error again... You said to use `Virtual Box` when I was using `Virtual Box` it was very lagging. That's why I deleted virtual box. And, I earlier left Kali for the same reason.

Comment: But, today mode is set to managed but, wlan0 isn't working..!